# How to implement create, update, delete in magento rest api?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api, web-services, amazon-web-services

How to set methods in `api2.xml` 
I create `_create(), _retrieve() , _update(), _delete(), _retrieveCollection()` functions in `Module/Model/Api2/Test/Rest/Guest/V1.php`

I think its manage in `/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Resource.php`

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the guide for extend REST API for Magento: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_extend_magento_rest_api.html